# How to listen for location providers becoming enabled / disabled?

Tags: android, locationmanager

Is it possible to get notified when a location provider becomes enabled or disabled, without it actually looking up the device's location (because doing so might use a lot of power)?

Answer (score 1):

In android there is LocationListener interface which provides a abstract method onProviderEnabled(String provider). So you have create your own listener and implement the onProviderEnabled(String provider) method. It is very must your listener must be register with location manager.

If do same as described above then onProviderEnabled(String provider) will called automatically when location provider became enable.

Answer (score 0):

[Locationmanager.isProviderEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't seem to require actually looking up the location. It won't be too efficient as you'd need to poll it, but it's better than getting the actual location.

Actually, reading a bit more on the topic, it seems you'd be able to use [requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to do this. It will send you a bundle with `KEY_PROVIDER_ENABLED` when the provider is enabled or disabled. You can set the minimum time and distance for notification to extremely high values. This way you'll get a location notification once in a while and mostly just enabled/disabled notifications.